# await Task using reflection in .Net for Store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, async-await, system.reflection

There is  a method which will take a Task as input and await.

```
protected async Task DoTask(Task t)
{
  //Do something
  await t;
}
```

The second method will accept the method name in string format and will create the method object using Reflection. Task needs to be created instead of invoking it and pass it to first method 
This two methods are part of a base class . The child class which is a view model will call DoTask2 and pass the name of the function defined inside itself(i.e.view model).

```
protected async Task DoTask2(string method)
        {Task t = null;
            var typeInfo = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
            var methods = typeInfo.DeclaredMethods;
            var meth = methods .Single(o => String.Equals(o.Name, method));

            t = meth .Invoke(this, null) as Task;   

      await DoTask(t);
}
```

But this is not working properly. Is something wrong here in the approach.

I am trying to build this in a windows 8.1 store app
EDIT:
Upon executing this line, instead getting the Task object, the async method is getting invoked. I need to get the task so that I can pass it to the next method.
.

I want to get the method using reflection but create it as a new Task execute using my doTask method. All methods are in the same class. Dotask and Dotask2 are in the base class.

Comment: *But this is not working properly* isn't very helpful. Instead say what's happening. Any exception? unexpected results? or what?

Comment: "But this is not working properly." - what happens?

Comment: I'm confused; is `DoTask` the method you are trying to invoke by reflection? Because right at the end of your reflection code, you execute `DoTask` on it. Is there actually a second method that is the one named for `methodname`? If so, can we see the declaration? Is the target method `public`, btw?

Comment: Instead of going through the TypeInfo, you can also just get the method from the type: `this.GetType().GetMethod(methodname).Invoke(this, null)`.

Comment: @poke does that continue to apply in Windows 8.1 store apps? the reflection codebase is different there

Comment: I ve updated the question with details.

Comment: Re your edit: "EDIT: Upon executing this line, instead getting the Task object, the async method is getting invoked." - yes, that is what **happens** when you invoke a method: the method gets invoked! Can you be more clear about your expectation versus what happens?

Comment: I see no reason to reflect on your own class at all. Why do you think you need reflection?

Comment: @MarcGravell [`Type.GetMethod(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6.aspx) is available on Windows Phone, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem here is one of expectation;

> I want to get the method using reflection but create it as a new Task execute using my doTask method.

That simply isn't how most async APIs *work*; invoking an `async` method: **is executing an `async` method** - or more specifically, it is executing the method as far as the first continuation that reports as incomplete. Invoking an `async` method **does not** just create an as-yet unstarted token to a method. I wonder if you might actually want a `Func<Task>` rather than a `Task` - a `Func<Task>` is a delegate that *returns* a `Task` when invoked - but without invoking it yet. There are ways to create a `Func<T>` directly from a `MethodInfo` in regular .NET, but in windows-store apps you might need to be indirect:

```
Func<Task> invoker = () => (Task)meth.Invoke(this, null);
```

You would then have:

```
private async Task DoTask(Func<Task> invoker)
{
  var t = invoker(); //Do something code goes somewhere in this method
  await t;
}
```